# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to build my signed apk but I am facing this error.

`[although its running fine on my phone while i am testing it]

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxPdn.png)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happened because of miss match in the dependencies.